# Sitemap parsing error

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap, xml-sitemap, xml

I've upload a sitemap file to google search console recently, but they tell that it could be read but has errors with namespace and namespace prefixes.

This is my sitemap and its structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset 
   xmlns="https://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
   xmlns:xhtml="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/"
   xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

   <url>
      <loc>https://www.bizibuz.com/</loc>
      <xhtml:link
         rel="alternate"
         hreflang="en"
         href="https://www.bizibuz.com/" />
      <xhtml:link
         rel="alternate"
         hreflang="zh-Hant"
         href="https://www.bizibuz.com/zh/" />
   </url>

...

   <url>
      <loc>https://www.bizibuz.com/preprimary-knowyourchild</loc>
      <xhtml:link
         rel="alternate"
         hreflang="en"
         href="https://www.bizibuz.com/preprimary-knowyourchild" />
      <xhtml:link
         rel="alternate"
         hreflang="zh-Hant"
         href="https://www.bizibuz.com/zh/preprimary-knowyourchild" />
      <video:video>
         <video:title>Pre-primary KnowYourChild™ Tools</video:title>
         <video:content_loc>https://bizibuz-web-dev.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/static/videos/Bizibuz KYC - pre primary 4_3.mp4</video:content_loc>
      </video:video>
      <video:video>
         <video:title>KnowYourChild™學前評估工具</video:title>
         <video:content_loc>https://bizibuz-web-dev.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/static/videos/Bizibuz KYC - pre primary 4_3 - cn.mp4</video:content_loc>
      </video:video>
   </url>

...

</urlset>
```

and the error detail is

```
Your Sitemap or Sitemap index file doesn't properly declare the namespace.
```

```
The XML Sitemap cannot be parsed because it contains one or more unbound namespace prefixes. For example, this error is generated when <xhtml:link> is found in a Sitemap without prior xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml".
```

```
error on line 41 at column 19: Namespace prefix video on video is not defined
error on line 42 at column 22: Namespace prefix video on title is not defined
error on line 43 at column 28: Namespace prefix video on content_loc is not defined
error on line 45 at column 19: Namespace prefix video on video is not defined
error on line 46 at column 22: Namespace prefix video on title is not defined
error on line 47 at column 28: Namespace prefix video on content_loc is not defined
error on line 61 at column 19: Namespace prefix video on video is not defined
error on line 62 at column 22: Namespace prefix video on title is not defined
error on line 63 at column 28: Namespace prefix video on content_loc is not defined
error on line 65 at column 19: Namespace prefix video on video is not defined
error on line 66 at column 22: Namespace prefix video on title is not defined
error on line 67 at column 28: Namespace prefix video on content_loc is not defined
error on line 81 at column 19: Namespace prefix video on video is not defined
error on line 82 at column 22: Namespace prefix video on title is not defined
error on line 83 at column 28: Namespace prefix video on content_loc is not defined
error on line 85 at column 19: Namespace prefix video on video is not defined
error on line 86 at column 22: Namespace prefix video on title is not defined
error on line 87 at column 28: Namespace prefix video on content_loc is not defined
```

Any idea to fix those issues? Am I missing something on configuration for `urlset`? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

They are google?

> but they tell that it could be read but has errors with namespace and
> namespace prefixes.

Well the missing namespace appears to be the xmlns:video, which I'm not seeing consistently used in google's how to, but it is listed in Google's best practices ... related to the rich search results to allow google to have a sniplet of the video to improve your listing.

[image]

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/video#videoobject

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
        xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1">
```

Comment: yes, thank you, namespace is missing when using the video tag on the sitemap. That could resolve the `Namespace prefix video` issue. Btw do you have any idea to fix `Your Sitemap or Sitemap index file doesn't properly declare the namespace` issue?

Comment: Only namespace not declared is the xmlns:video ... https://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1/ with all the options video:title etc listed in https://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1/sitemap-video.xsd